# вывод значений переменных printf()

Tags: c++, c, вывод

есть код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    void    main(void)
    { 
    int x=5, y=60;
    x++; 
     ++y;   
    printf(“x=%d y%d\n”,x,y);
    printf(“x=%d y%d\n”,x++,++y);
int d=x--;
printf(“d=%d d %d\n”,d);
int c=--x;
printf(“c=%d c%d\n”,c);
}
```

Вывод:

```
x=6 y61
x=6 y62
d=7 d 898
c=5 c898
```

Вопрос: откуда берутся значения 898? Я понимаю, что они выводятся, потому что я пишу 2 формата переменных, а в аргументы подаю лишь одну, но откуда берутся значения 898 для второго формата?

Comment: Из места в памяти, где **могла бы быть** ваша переменная...

Comment: Лучше бы предупреждения прочитал, чем вопросы задавать. Да ещё и с испорченными кавычками.